# How to fix image not displaying in php?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

So I am trying to create a CTA(call to action) adding three cards into my wordpress site. I am trying to insert PHP and ACF functions so that it shows my image, currently it displays the title and the body text of these cards but doesn't show any image? How do I fix it?

In my acf, I have created four sub field types: "cta_image", "cta_title", "intro_text" and "cta_link". In my code editor, I have inserted the following functions and so far on my wordpress site, it shows the title and the intro text but I don't know how to put an image.

```
<?php

if ( have_rows( 'ctas' ) ) :
    // Loop through rows (parent repeater).
    while ( have_rows( 'ctas' ) ) :
        the_row();
?>

    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'cta_title' ) ) : ?>
            <h2><?php the_sub_field( 'cta_title' ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>


    <div class="body-text">
        <?php print_r(get_sub_field('intro_text')); ?>
    </div>


    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Every time I insert functions to show the image, it gives a database error or simply doesn't show any image. The final work is supposed to look like the image down below. Mine shows just the title and body text all in a single line.

Comment: What does the code that you've tried look like. Also, have you tried the Basic display from the act documentation? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: PHP doesn't display images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this bit of code directly from the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)?

```
<?php $image = get_sub_field('cta_image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I did but it doesn't show any image and says "database error..unexpected endif" and i deleted the endif and still shows no image

Comment: I misspelled the starting php tag. That might be the reason for the error. However, can you please share a screenshot of the full code?

Comment: Hello Gul. Thankyou for the code above, I fixed the errors again and now shows the whole image. I was also wondering how to structure those three ctas so they all display inline like in the picture above? I tried adjusting the width and height however, they dont all show on a same line next to each other.

Comment: Gul, thankyou for saving me from hours of frustration. I really really appreciate your help. It worked just as it needed to. Thankyou so much again

Comment: You're most welcome Nancy. Also, if you don't mind, can you select my answer as the selected answer? TIA.